# How to detect language preference in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, locale

I want to detect my client language by getting the browser recommended language.

For Example, if you open the browser in Japan it will give me country code or country name current user opened like "en-jp" or "japan".

I try this code but it seems to display the language that I previously selected and by default it's English.

I set a Middleware and I need to exclude the api part because I have some routers pinging this address and router browser does not have language information which brick the system.

```
class BeforeMiddleware
{

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param  \Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */

protected $except_urls = [
    'api/*'
];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $langArr = array("en", "fr");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
        $languages = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    } else {
        $languages[0] = "en";
    }
    if (Session::has('locale')) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    } else {
        if (in_array($languages[0], $langArr))
            App::setLocale($languages[0]);
    }
    return $next($request);
}


} /* end class */
```

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To simply get the locale from the header, you can grab the `http-accept-language` value from the request. This is accessible via a facade or you can use the request variable in your middleware:

```
Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')

// OR

$request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

This returns a string which looks like this: `en-GB,en;q=0.8`. You can then parse it (perhaps using `explode()`?) and grab the language from there.

However, this sort of thing can sometimes get complicated. If you need to do something more advanced, there's a package which can do all of this for you:

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: parsing this is tricky, which is why It think Daniels answer is preferrable.

Answer (score 39):

Or you can use `Illuminate\Http\Request::getPreferredLanguage`

Like this, in middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Locale {

  const SESSION_KEY = 'locale';
  const LOCALES = ['en', 'cs'];

  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
    /** @var Session $session */
    $session = $request->getSession();

    if (!$session->has(self::SESSION_KEY)) {
      $session->put(self::SESSION_KEY, $request->getPreferredLanguage(self::LOCALES));
    }

    if ($request->has('lang')) {
      $lang = $request->get('lang');
      if (in_array($lang, self::LOCALES)) {
        $session->put(self::SESSION_KEY, $lang);
      }
    }

    app()->setLocale($session->get(self::SESSION_KEY));

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Comment: The use of `getPreferredLanguage` is prefect, because it is a built-in. It is part of the `Symphony` framework, and is automatically provided.

Comment: @TimVisée thanks Tim, I was curious where this was documented and couldn't find it in Laravel. See symphony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/47da6640f8f88d56968813247806148283106b82/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1644

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but why store this in the session?  Why not just `app()->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(self::LOCALES))`

Comment: @Roddy little late, but basically you have to save somewhere if user change his locale manually, by your approach, its just browser preffered lang on every request

Answer (score 8):

I just made a Middleware for this, it may be useful.

First you set `$availableLangs` the array of the available languages in your app, you may use `config\app.php` instead of initializing the array in the middleware as I did.

If the first language is available in the request language data, it sets the locale, if not, it will search the next one, and so on.

```
class GetRequestLanguage
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        } else {
            $availableLangs = ['pt', 'en'];
            $userLangs = preg_split('/,|;/', $request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));

            foreach ($availableLangs as $lang) {
                if(in_array($lang, $userLangs)) {
                    App::setLocale($lang);
                    Session::push('locale', $lang);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but the problem is that you force the locale order using `$availableLangs` instead using order defined in `$userLangs`. Looping through `$userLangs` and checking if defined in `$availableLangs` should work. We should always follow the browser preferred language choice.

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but i'll apply my anwser.
If you want to automatic localization use the bellow code in your Middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{   
    $asTranslation = ['en','pt'];
    $userLocales = $request->getLanguages();
    $locale = Str::before($request->getPreferredLanguage($userLocales),'_');

    //check if the locale is in the array of available locales
    if (!in_array($locale, $asTranslation)) {
        $locale = 'en';
    }
    //remove the brackets from the locale
    app()->setLocale( Str::before($locale, '_'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a middleware do:

```php
$acceptableLocales = config('app.available_locales');
$userLocales = $request->getLanguages();

if(!empty($userLocales)) {
    foreach ($userLocales as $lang) {
        $langToSearch = str_replace('_','-',$lang);
        if(in_array($langToSearch, $acceptableLocales)) {
            app('translator')->setLocale($langToSearch);
            break;
        }
    }
}

return $next($request);
```

If you want to return the language in the response to the client, create another middleware and do:

```php
/** @var Response $response */
$response = $next($request);
$response->header('Content-Language', app('translator')->getLocale());
return $response;
```

Comment: If your folder names use underscores, then you don't need the str_replace. This is only there because of my implementation i.e. en-GB as opposed to en_GB

Answer (score 1):

Detect language in Route and redirect to /en, /es, or ...

File web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $lang = config('app.locale');
    try {
        $lang = Request::getPreferredLanguage(config('app.locales'));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
    }
    return redirect()->to($lang);
});
```

File config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'es',
'locales' => ['es','en'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a middleware too, but a lit bit smaller.

```
<?php

namespace Transfer\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLanguage
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = $request->getLocale();

        if ($request->session()->has('locale')) {
            $locale = $request->session()->get('locale');
        }

        config(['app.locale' => $locale]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For Laravel 8 you can use $request->segment(1)

Example of Request:
Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE') = en-DE,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de;q=0.6

Code:
$request->segment(1)

Result:
'en'

So easily set the locale: \App::setlocale($request->segment(1));

Comment: Result: null. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This will return the first part of the URL, the part after the domain. If your URL is `example.com/en/products/1` it will return the `en` part. If you're not putting the locale in your URL, this solution will not work.