# Does laravel not detect request locale automatically?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-localization

I am learning laravel 5.4 locale chapter. When I write code to test, I get a question. For example, I have two language directories in my `resources/lang` directory:

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            messages.php
        /zh-CN
            messages.php
```

I set default locale is `zh-CN`, fallback locale is `en`. When I set `Accept-Language` to `zh-CN`, I can get translation string in zh-CN. But when I set `Accept-Language` to `en`, I still get string in zh-CN. So laravel does not detect request locale automatically? And If my application want to show english to those `Accept-Language` is `en`, and show chinese to those `Accept-Language` is `zh-CN`, I need to do it manually, is that correct? I though laravel will detect request locale automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect language preference in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986236/how-to-detect-language-preference-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 1):

First configure the available languages in your `config/app.php`.

```
    'available_locales' => array('en', 'de', 'fr', 'it'),
```

Now add this code to your `routes/web.php`. It will detect the browser language and set the locale if the language is available.

```
    $availableLanguages = Config::get('app.available_locales');
    $lang = Request::getPreferredLanguage($availableLanguages);
    if ($lang) Config::set('app.locale', $lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing those changes it is always recommended to run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```