# Detect country from ip and redirect to according country

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect the website according to detect country from IP address and redirect it to according country. ex. http://www.test.com/in/contact, http://www.test.com/us/contact. How do I achieve that in laravel ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what error you get

Comment: @palI i tried for it but it gives me 404 error.

Comment: - Always good to state what you have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this post [How to detect language preference in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986236/how-to-detect-language-preference-in-laravel-5)
you can get the language form the header with the code below and redirect accordingly

```
Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')

// OR

$request->server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```