# In laravel, How to change the language of site per user's location automatically

Tags: laravel, localization

I'm going to implement the multi-language feature in my Laravel website.

```
php artisan --version
```

> Laravel Framework 7.30.6

I've realized that the best library is the Torann / laravel-geoip by torann.

So, I was going to use this library via composer install, but have got errors like below

```
composer require torann/geoip
```

```
/composer.json has been updated
Running composer update torann/geoip
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies

************ Start of the Error Section **************
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - torann/geoip[3.0.1, ..., 3.0.2] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.        
    - torann/geoip 3.0.3 requires php ^8.0 -> your php version (7.4.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires torann/geoip ^3.0 -> satisfiable by torann/geoip[3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
************ End of the Error Section *******************
```

I was trying to solve this problem with online resources, but failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: I think there is better solution than geo - browser locale

The language of the page does not depend on my location, but on my user settings

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986236/how-to-detect-language-preference-in-laravel-5/49158689#49158689